# Extract after comparing set of consecutive rows from another view Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, relational-division

Hi I want to get the sequence id from a view after comparing the set of rows from another view.
I can do listagg and group by sequence id  and match that listagg with other view.But is there any other option.
View 1 has seq_id in order 0,1,2,3,4....and pattern id is also is in order. We can have ROW_NUMBER()over() has the ordering for pattern id

```
WITH view1(seq_id, pattern_id,rnum) AS (SELECT 0 , 1 ,1 FROM dual UNION
SELECT 0 , 2,2 FROM dual UNION
SELECT 0 , 3,3 FROM dual UNION
SELECT 0 , 4,4 FROM dual UNION
SELECT 1 , 3,5 FROM dual UNION
SELECT 1 , 4,6 FROM dual UNION
SELECT 1 , 1,7 FROM dual UNION
SELECT 1 , 2,8 FROM dual UNION
SELECT 2 , 2,9 FROM dual UNION
SELECT 2 , 4,10 FROM dual UNION
SELECT 2 , 1,11 FROM dual UNION
SELECT 2 , 3,12 FROM dual )

SELECT * FROM view1 order by rnum;
```

Example :

*View 1*

```
    seq id   pattern
    ------   -------
    0          1
    0          2
    0          3
    0          4
    1          3
    1          4
    1          1
    1          2
    2          2
    2          3
    2          5
    2          1
```

*View 2* has another column pk_id which is unique sequence like a rownum. Always start with 1

```
   pk_id   pattern id
  ------  ------------
    1        3
    2        4
    3        1
    4        2
```

Expected output from View 1

```
    seq id
    ------
    1
```

Comment: In SQL, result sets without an `ORDER BY` clause are non-deterministically ordered so there is no obvious reason why the output for `3,4,1,2` would match `1` and not `0` as they both contain the same values. If you want to order the results set then you need another column to use to define the order.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE VIEW` statements for your views; the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables referenced by the views; and `INSERT` statements for your sample data.

Comment: Actually the first view needs some kind of ordering column as well @RajivA.

Comment: What about view1? It has to have some kind of ordering information too. Otherwise seq_id 0 and 1 are equally right answers

Comment: What if a seq_id in view 1 has *more* patterns than the list of view 2, should it appear in the results?

Comment: View 1 has seq_id in order 0,1,2,3,4.....and pattern id is always in order. We can define rownum as order .Regarding if more  than 1 pattern then pick the first seq id where it matches the pattern.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. PS Dumps of requirements are off-topic. How are you stuck having done what? [mre] [ask] [Help]PS See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify 1 non-sole non-poster commenter `x` per comment about that comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified. Without `@` other commenters get no notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function to index each sequence in `view1` and then compare it to `view2` and find the sequence which matches all the rows of the sequence:

```sql
SELECT seq_id,
       MIN(rnum) AS pattern_start
FROM   ( SELECT v1.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY seq_id ORDER BY rnum) AS rn,
                COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY seq_id) AS num_patterns
         FROM   view1 v1
       ) v1
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT v2.*,
                COUNT(*) OVER () AS num_patterns
         FROM   view2 v2
       ) v2
       ON     v1.rn           = v2.pk_id
          AND v1.pattern_id   = v2.pattern_id
          AND v1.num_patterns = v2.num_patterns
GROUP BY seq_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = MAX(v1.num_patterns);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE VIEW view1 (seq_id, pattern_id, rnum) AS
  SELECT 0, 1,  1 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 2,  2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 3,  3 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 0, 4,  4 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 3,  5 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 4,  6 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 1,  7 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 2,  8 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2,  9 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4, 10 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1, 11 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 3, 12 FROM dual
  ORDER BY 3;

CREATE VIEW view2 (pk_id, pattern_id) AS
  SELECT 1, 3 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 2 FROM dual
  ORDER BY 1;
```

Outputs:

| SEQ_ID | PATTERN_START |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/k2Z_jMS5)

Comment: @MT0 Thank you so much for your effort and time. I have one change in requirement :-( The seq id in VIEW 1 is not important and the pattern can go across sequence. I need to get the rnum value.It can be start or end of the pattern. Again the first occurrence of the pattern

Comment: According to the new request ,we have to remove the partitioning by seq id,because the pattern can be across sequence and I have to get the start or end of the rnum. In other words seq id is of no use

Comment: @RajivA If you want to ask a new question with new requirements then [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Do not suddenly change an existing question to have completely new requirements.

Comment: Yes I was thinking so to put a new question. I am actually getting multiple inputs from different users and so lost. Sorry for all this mess up. I feel bad wasting everyone's time.I will try to write a proc to loop and get it

Comment: @RajivA You possibly want something like [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/y8MHpieN)

Comment: wow!!  it worked and pretty straight forward. That group by subtraction logic is awesome :-). Why I could not get this. Thank you so very much! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

`listagg` looks like a rather relevant approach. An alternative is to use a relational division technique:

```
select v1.seq_id
from (
    select v1.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by seq_id order by rnum) pk_id
    from view1 v1
) v1
inner join view2 v2 
    on  v2.pattern_id = v1.pattern_id
    and v2.pk_id = v1.pk_id
group by v1.seq_id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from view2)
```

If you want to exclude seq_ids that contain *more* patterns than the reference, we can `left join` instead:

```
select v1.seq_id
from (
    select v1.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by seq_id order by rnum) pk_id
    from view1 v1
) v1
left join view2 v2 
    on  v2.pattern_id = v1.pattern_id
    and v2.pk_id = v1.pk_id
group by v1.seq_id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from view2)
   and count(*) = count(v2.pk_id)
```